# How do I install "R" on macOS using homebrew?

Tags: homebrew

How do I install "[R](https://www.r-project.org/)" on macOS? Ideally using Homebrew?

There seems to be very little information online.

Comment: Note people finding this answer who just want to install R the normal way should see the second [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/121410/11747) here that mentions how to get the standard installation files.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20457290/3924118 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/29017001/3924118.

Comment: for you guys who stumble upon this, especially who use Mojave++ consider to install it from CRAN instead homebrew, ref: https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyverse/issues/154 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50229781/package-installation-in-r-fail-on-macos/50252325

Answer (score 117):

**Install Homebrew (if needed)**

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

**Install R**

```
brew tap homebrew/science
brew install r
```

Comment: I also ran "brew install gfortran" beforehand, but I don't think it was necessary. If someone could please confirm...

Comment: Indeed, Homebrew should automatically install all required dependencies.

Comment: With this method are you able to install packages from CRAN? I was unable to get packages from CRAN to install correctly when I installed R using brew. When I switched to a copy of R downloaded directly from CRAN, my problems went away.

Comment: Warning: r installed this way [may not cooperate with RStudio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27659520/).

Comment: I didn't see gfortran in the dependencies it installs with homebrew. It's not technically a required dependency anyway. It's only necessary if you install packages that require it.

Comment: Depends on `Caskroom/cask/xquartz` (not automatic)

Comment: @PiotrMigdal Currently (April 2017) it works with RStudio again.

Comment: Thanks @Xiang. i have no occasion installing r via brew so far. what do you say about installing packages as of today?

Comment: Why is `curl` wrapped in `ruby`?

Comment: I got `Error: homebrew/science was deprecated. This tap is now empty as all its formulae were migrated.` while trying out `brew tap homebrew/science`

Comment: for you guys who stumble upon this, especially who use Mojave++ consider to install it from CRAN instead homebrew, ref: https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyverse/issues/154 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50229781/package-installation-in-r-fail-on-macos/50252325

Answer (score 31):

Assuming you **just want to install “R” on OS X** and are not interested in homebrew:

Just download the binary from CRAN https://cloud.r-project.org/

1. Go to http://www.r-project.org/
2. Click CRAN
3. Select a mirror
4. Click ["download R for (Mac) OS X"](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/)
5. Download and install the latest pkg binary

See also the [R for Mac OSX FAQ](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/RMacOSX-FAQ.html) that includes information on installation.

Note also the comments below suggesting that homebrew is often not the best option.

Comment: Installing Yosemite (re)moved my old R, and I wanted it back. I initially thought to install R using brew, but after following the instructions on this page I ended up with a trainwreck that didn't work correctly and took a while to remove. Not to mention that it ran for hours overnight installing gcc and lots of other things I didn't need or want. After clearing up and hoping "brew doctor" was right, I when to CRAN and downloaded the installer and within 5 minutes had a fully working R with no fuss at all. All I had to do was re-source my terminal. I should have used CRAN first.

Comment: Was your old R under Yosemite installed using brew as well?

Comment: +25: ***Just install via r-project.org package.*** I am a `brew` fan, but it was NOT the right way to install R in my case because of `gcc` dependency catastrophe; save yourself.

Comment: +1 for your "+25" -- if you're going to get serious with R and take advantage of all it has to offer, choose this answer.

Comment: If only there were a brew cask for this!

Comment: what's it with gcc.. i think i ran into trouble trying to install Octave some time.. does't homebrew ever try to solve these issues

Comment: I just installed r via brew with no occasion.

Comment: Where is it after this? I'm trying to run R by typing "R" on the command line and it just tells me -bash: R: command not found

Answer (score 17):

After following [Matt Burns' answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/121402/74310), you can also install the R.app GUI via `brew cask`:

```
$ brew tap caskroom/cask
$ brew cask install r-app
$ open /Applications/R.app
```

Comment: Thanks. One thing, though: You might want to edit the last line in your script so that it reads `brew linkapps r-gui` instead of merely `brew linkapps`.

Comment: this failed miserably for me. Ended up just following this tutorial on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tnhp65hxtZc

Comment: I get the following error, if I try to execute `brew install r-gui`: `Error: No available formula with the name "r-gui". It was migrated from homebrew/science to caskroom/cask/r-app. You can access it again by running: "brew tap caskroom/cask".`.

Comment: As of 2019/04/14: `Jasons-MacBook-Pro:20190402_Tuesday_PM_captures harrison$ brew cask install r-app
Error: Cask 'r-app' is unavailable: No Cask with this name exists.`

Answer (score 6):

You can download R for Mac OS X simply from here : http://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu

Hit the button : `Download R for (Mac) OS X`

Install the PKG file that came in the download.

This website might help to go ahead and download home-brew / install home brew as well.

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Installation

Answer (score 2):

I'm a fan of [RStudio](http://www.rstudio.com). It's an IDE that wraps R, makes visualization, organization, debugging, and other tasks *much* easier. Or, you can just use it as if it were a simple install of R. There's a Mac binary available from that website.

Comment: To use Rstudio, you first have to install R…

Comment: I'm pretty sure RStudio ships with a version of R, but it may not be the most recent version. When I did it it was several versions behind the current one.  You then need a separate installation of R to be current.

Comment: Beginners should definitely use RStudio.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled onto this trying to install R in general and I ended up using MacPorts. If your using MacPorts, try

```
sudo port install R
```

Taken from http://johnlaudun.org/20140721-install-r-with-macports/

Answer (score 0):

1.- http://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/ and download in Mac-GUI-1.62.tar.gz.
2.- INSTALL

You need R built and installed as a framework: see the 'R Installation
and Administration Manual'.  A CRAN binary install of R suffices.

## Building R.app

Only Mac OS X 10.6 and higher are supported, and only 64-bit R. The
project is called "R.xcodeproj" and requires Xcode 3.2 or higher.

The project can be built by selecting "R" target and "Build" inside
the XCode GUI.

Supported configurations are:
  SnowLeopard64 (release, current OS X, default)
  Lion64 (release, OS X 10.7+, Xcode 4.5+)
  MLion64 (release, OS X 10.8+, Xcode 4.5+)
  Debug (with debugging output, current OS X)

The configurations differ mainly in the SDK selected (recent versions
of Xcode only support the current and immediately previous SDKs, so
for example in Mar 2013 the default would build for 10.8, but
configuration Lion64 allows building for >= 10.7).

To build the project from the command line in the Mac-GUI directory
use something like:
    xcodebuild -target R -configuration SnowLeopard64

To build the R for Mac OS X FAQ use either
    xcodebuild -target Docs
or manually in docs folder
    makeinfo -D UseExternalXrefs --html --force --no-split RMacOSX-FAQ.texi

The resulting html FAQ file will be found in Mac-GUI/docs directory.

Note about binary compatibility:

The general rules for R apply, that is binary compatibility is given
only if the major and minor version numbers match - only the patch
level may differ. When using the X.Y.Z version form it means that X.Y
must match. For example R-GUIs linked to 3.0.x and 3.1.x are NOT
binary compatible.

The compiled R.app is usually bound to a specific version, such as
3.0.1. If you upgrade R removing the older version, let's say using
R.app built for 3.0.0 and updating R to 3.0.1, you may need to fix the
absolute path to libR.dylib. The nightly builds use a generic path
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib/libR.dylib which points
to the latest version of R, but this is done by an additional call to
install_name_tool in the building script.  Release versions of the GUI
use a fixed-version path as they come with a specific R version (in fact
the default behavior doesn't depends on the GUI, but on libR.dylib -
changing its own reference entry changes the way R.app is linked).